# Running a Python script to copy files into a folder after the compile goal

Tags: maven, file, copy

I have a text file containing a list of files in my build. When building with Maven, after the compile goal, I need to create a folder and copy the files mentioned in the text file (along with the folder structure in their respective projects) to a new folder within the build that will be created as part of build time. This folder will then be used by an assembly descriptor to create a distributable tar file.

I am not much familiar with Maven. Is there any feature in Maven that I can use to accompolish this? Or should I create some script that will be called by Maven as a part of one of it's goals to copy the files?

Comment: I'd stick with some custom script either in Groovy (then you should use gmaven plugin), or in some other language (then you should use exec plugin).

Comment: What does this text file contain? Which files have been compiled or what? Why do you need such kind of file?

Comment: The idea there is to create a distributable that contains only certain specific files that are listed in the said text file. The script is to get the file names from the text file and copy the required files with the relevant folder structure into a new folder in the build and create an assembly descriptor to pack the folder into the distributable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the aim of maven is to prepare, compile, test and package.

But as all the IT projects are different, maven allows you to extend its behaviour.

What you are needing is very specific to your business, so you'll have to write your own script that parses the list and copies the files somewhere.

For instance:

```
cat myListOfFiles | xargs -d "\n" -I '{}'  cp '{}' /somewhere/in/my/project/'{}'
```

Then, you can easily launch a script after the compilation phase (named: `process-classes`).

You just need to add the plugin configuration as below:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-my-files</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>my-script.sh</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>/path/to/the/file-list</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

HIH

Comment: This isn't very helpful in regards to when the exec phase is actually run. If I run ``mvn compile`` will it run this phase?